# Hide empty row in an email report

Tags: javascript, php, css, email

I need help with this code. The javascript code and style in the header tag are used to hide empty row because not all the rows have data in them and this works when displaying on my web page.
But when I use it to send a report to an **email address** as a report the empty row displays. 
Is there something I need to consider to get it to hide empty rows in the **email of the receiver.**
Below are the code:

```
enter$sql = mysqli_query($con_path, "SELECT * FROM classscore WHERE emailsent=0 LIMIT 20");
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
$mail_body = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
$studentid = $row['student_id'];
$classname = $row['class_name'];
$english  =  $row['english'];
$maths = $row['maths'];
$accounts = $row['accounts'];
$music = $row['music'];
$email = $row['email'];

$mail_body = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Report</title>
<style>
.hide { 
display: none; 
}
</style>
</head>

 <body>
 <table id="table" width="40%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius:10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px; color:#000;">
<tr>
<td width="23%">Student ID</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td> '.$studentid.' / '.$classname.'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Subjects</strong></td>
<td width="21%"><strong>Overall Score</strong></td>
<td width="56%"><strong>Actual Score</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>English</td>
<td>100</td>
<td> '.$english.'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Maths</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>'.$maths.'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Account</td>
<td>100</td>
<td> '.$accounts.'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Music</td>
<td>100</td>
<td> '.$music.'</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<script language="javascript">
var tbl = document.getElementById("table");
var rows = tbl.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

var cells = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td");

var flag = true;
//this number controls the colunm the code will check before it disappears.
for(j = 2; j < cells.length; j++) {
    if (cells[j].innerHTML != 0) { 
        flag = false; 
    }
}


if(flag) { 
    rows[i].classList.add("hide"); 
}
}                                      
</script>
</body>
</html>';
$subject = "Report";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers  = "From:schoolreport@pearlgateconsult.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$to = "$email";

$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);

if ($mail_result) {
    mysqli_query($con_path, "UPDATE classscore SET emailsent=1 WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
} else {

}

}

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<?php echo $mail_body; ?>
<body>
</body>
</html>

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS classscore ;
CREATE TABLE classscore
(student_id INTEGER (11) NULL,
email varchar(255),
class_name varchar(255),
english INTEGER (11) NULL,
maths INTEGER (11) NULL,
accounts INTEGER (11) NULL,
music INTEGER (11) NULL,
emailsent varchar(255) DEFAULT '0'
);

INSERT INTO classscore
(student_id,email,class_name,english,maths,accounts,music) VALUES
(10011,'tosinsog@gmail.com','Basic1','70','80','75',''),
(10012,'tosinsog@gmail.com','Basic1','55','','','69'),
(10013,'tosinsog@gmail.com','Basic1','74','75','','85'),
(10014,'tosinsog@gmail.com','Basic1','64','84','58',''),
(10015,'tosinsog@gmail.com','Basic1','69','','65','73'),
(10016,'tosinsog@gmail.com','Basic1','70','80','74','68'),
(10017,'tosinsog@gmail.com','Basic1','75','82','','');
```

So email report works but the empty rows are not to be displayed in the email report when the receiver gets it. I would really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code if it could solve your problem.

```
 $mail_body = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Report</title>
 <style>
  .hide { 
     display: none; 
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
   <table id="table" width="40%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius:10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px; color:#000;">
  <tr>
     <td width="23%">Student ID</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td> '.$studentid.' / '.$classname.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><strong>Subjects</strong></td>
     <td width="21%"><strong>Overall Score</strong></td>
     <td width="56%"><strong>Actual Score</strong></td>
  </tr>';

  if($english!=0){

  $mail_body.='<tr>
     <td>English</td>
     <td>100</td>
     <td> '.$english.'</td>
  </tr>'; }

  if($maths!=0) { 
   $mail_body.='<tr>
     <td>Maths</td>
     <td>100</td>
     <td>'.$maths.'</td>
  </tr>'; }

  if($accounts!=0){
  $mail_body.='<tr>
     <td>Account</td>
     <td>100</td>
     <td> '.$accounts.'</td>
  </tr>'; }

  if($music!=0){
  $mail_body.='<tr>
      <td>Music</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td> '.$music.'</td>
  </tr>'; }
$mail_body.='</table>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<script language="javascript">
   var tbl = document.getElementById("table");
   var rows = tbl.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

   for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

    var cells = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td");

    var flag = true;
    //this number controls the colunm the code will check before it disappears.
   for(j = 2; j < cells.length; j++) {
     if (cells[j].innerHTML != 0) { 
      flag = false; 
     }
    }


   if(flag) { 
      rows[i].classList.add("hide"); 
   }
 }                                      
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>';
 $subject = "Report";
 $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
 $headers  = "From:schoolreport@pearlgateconsult.com\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
 $to = "$email";

 $mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);

  if ($mail_result) {
    mysqli_query($con_path, "UPDATE classscore SET emailsent=1 WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
  }

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<?php echo $mail_body; ?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work and it did not send the report too. The problem I am trying to solve is that each students' report is meant to display only the rows with score when it gets to their respective email box. if the four rows have score it displays all four rows, if two scores it displays two rows, if three scores it displays three rows when they get their scores emailed to them.

Comment: I have made changes in main answer, try if it can work for you

Comment: Thanks again, but it is still displaying the rows with empty 0 in the email of the recipient. The report is sent to gmail, so maybe gmail is not allowing the script to hide the empty row.

Comment: Change if ($english!='') statement and any other to if (!empty($english) || $english!= 0)

Comment: @shubhangee & @ Gabor , thank you both, these works. Either of these works fine,  Changeif($english!='')  to if (!empty($english) || $english!= 0)  or Change if($english!='')  to if($english!= 0)